# Vue.js (vue-resource) app structure problems with sending HTTP request

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My Vue.js app structure is like so:

```
/app
    --assets
    --components
        --dashboard.vue
    --filters
    --views
        --dashboard-view.vue
    app.vue
    main.js
```

In my `main.js` file I have the snippet of code below to set up `vue-resource` to make HTTP requests:

```
Vue.use(require('vue-resource'))

Vue.http.options.root = 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/'
Vue.http.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('authentication_token')
```

However, when I try to make an HTTP request in `dashboard-view.vue` it doesn't listen to the configuration set in `main.js`.

This is `dashboard-view.vue`:

```
<template>
...
</template>

<script>
module.exports = {
  ready: function() {
    this.$http.get('/me', function(data, status, request) {

    })
  }
}
</script>
```

I'm quite new to Vue.js so help is appreciated on how to structure my app so I can easily send HTTP requests.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the ready: function is firing after the code in main.js runs? If not, I would add some console.log calls to prove it.

Answer (score 4):

I was having this same issue. When vue-resource concatenates the `root` option with the `url` parameter, it adds a backslash between them by default. If you already have a backslash at the end of your `root` option or at the beginning of any of your `url` parameters, it will just skip the concatenation and default to the current root url.

Just change your root option declaration to:

`Vue.http.options.root = 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1'`

and also change your call in the vue component to:

```
<template>
...
</template>

<script>
module.exports = {
  ready: function() {
    this.$http.get('me', function(data, status, request) {

    })
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Did my answer help you at all, Noah?